# Fade out image shown on hover after mouse leaves area using CSS

Tags: html, css

working on my new homepage, in wordpress but using the html editor because wordpress themes slow my site down like all hec. I'm nearly ready to go, just wondering how I accomplish the following:

[On my staging page here you can see](https://pausethemoment.photography/staging-landing-page-2)
Another image appears in front of it. I want that image to fade out after the mouse moves off the image.

Here's my code that got it going:

```
<div class="imageBox">
<div class="imageInn">
    <img src="https://pausethemoment.photography/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Melbourne-Wedding-Photography-Pause-The-Moment-Beach-Wedding-Photography-610x345.jpg" alt="Sandringham Melbourne Wedding Photography - Sun sets on couple on a beach.">
</div>
<div class="hoverImg">
    <a href="https://pausethemoment.photography/contact-us/"><img src="https://pausethemoment.photography/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Wedding-Photography-Melbourne-Limited-Dates-Overlay.png" alt="Pause The Moment Melbourne Wedding Photography" width="610" height="345" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-14308" /></a>
</div>
</div>
```

And then this CSS:

```
.imageBox 
    {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
    .imageBox .hoverImg {
        visibility:hidden;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    }
    .imageBox:hover .hoverImg {        
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Have tried using the ::after tag on

```
 .imageBox .hoverimage
```

in various formats like this:

```
.imageBox:hover::after .hoverImg 
        {
        visibility:visible;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        }
```

but to no avail. Have also played around with animation delays etc, but can't seem to get it to stay on there!  Tried webkit transitions but I couldn't even get them to fade it in. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with using the visibility property. CSS transition doesn't know how to generate intermediate values between "visible" and "hidden" because those values are not numeric.

Try removing all occurrences of visibility and applying the transition to opacity only.

```
.imageBox {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.imageBox .hoverImg {
    /*visibility:hidden;*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: /*visibility 0s,*/ opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.imageBox:hover .hoverImg {        
    display: block;
    /*visibility: visible;*/
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much for that. Posted working CSS in your answer. You sir, are a lifesaver!